# why the camera won't rotate around my object?

Tags: unity, c#, camera, rotate

im new to unity scripting, and now am building upon "Roll a Ball" example in unity training. I wanted to make the camera rotate around the ball in the scene in Y axis, when mouse is moved, and watched some tutorials on it, and eventually wrote the code below. but it doesn't rotate around the ball. instead it does a simple rotate in place. camera still moves with the ball though.
what am i doing wrong?

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Player;
    private Vector3 offset;

    public float moveSpeed;
    private Vector3 point;


    void Start () {
        offset = transform.position - Player.transform.position;

        point = Player.transform.position;
        transform.LookAt(point);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseMovement = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

        transform.RotateAround(point, new Vector3(0f, mouseMovement, 0f) , moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }


    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = Player.transform.position + offset;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from setting the position of the camera in late update. Change your LateUpdate code to something like this and remove the code from Update

```
 void LateUpdate()
    {
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
        transform.position = player.position + offset;
        transform.LookAt(player.position);
    }
```

Comment: ahh. thought op couldn't just rotate with his current code. +1 from me. (y)

Comment: thanks a lot man, that did exactly what i wanted. though is there any way to tweak my current code to do the same? im only asking for learning purposes.

Comment: Well I dont think so because your current   code fights for the position of the camera object. By fight I mean that both RotateAround and the code that follows the player set the position thus resulting in the cam rotating in place. The code I provided keeps the rotation and positioning separate which is what you want. Read this to completely understand RotateAround. [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)

Comment: i see. well thanks again. and i hope i don't be too much of a bother, but one more question. what exactly " * offset" does at the end of the first line? or more specifically, the " * " in lines like this in general.

Comment: * simply means multiplication. For example if you do print(2*2) this will output 4 to the console.

Comment: i understand that, i just dont get how a quaternion is multiplied by a vector3. could you in short explain what happened in this line? i just cant make any sense of it!

Comment: You can use the Quaternion.operator * to rotate one rotation by another, or to rotate a vector by a rotation. Again taken from the unity docs. This is a thing called operator overloading where you change the normal behavior of a operator to fit the specific need.